# This Virtual Directory does not allow objects to be executed

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

after copying my app to the hosting company servers there is such an error:

This Virtual Directory does not allow objects to be executed.

Have You got any idea why this error occurs ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

In IIS manager there is Execute permission on WebSite property tab. It probably must be checked in your case. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265161